# Modifying files nested in tar archive

Tags: linux, shell, unix, archive, tar

I am trying to do a `grep` and then a `sed` to search for specific strings inside files, which are inside multiple tars, all inside one master tar archive. Right now, I modify the files by

1. First extracting the master tar archive.
2. Then extracting all the tars inside it.
3. Then doing a recursive `grep` and then `sed` to replace a specific string in files.
4. Finally packaging everything again into tar archives, and all the archives inside the master archive.

Pretty tedious. How do I do this automatically using shell scripting?

Comment: Note that `sed` can usually do the selection that you'd use `grep` for at the same time it's doing the modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't going to be much option except automating the steps you outline, for the reasons demonstrated by the caveats in the answer by [Kimvais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180174/kimvais).

#### tar modify operations

The `tar` command has some options to modify existing tar files.  They are, however, not appropriate for your scenario for multiple reasons, one of them being that it is the nested tarballs that need editing rather than the master tarball.  So, you will have to do the work longhand.

#### Assumptions

Are all the archives in the master archive extracted into the current directory or into a named/created sub-directory?  That is, when you run `tar -tf master.tar.gz`, do you see:

```
subdir-1.23/tarball1.tar
subdir-1.23/tarball2.tar
...
```

or do you see:

```
tarball1.tar
tarball2.tar
```

(Note that nested tars should not themselves be gzipped if they are to be embedded in a bigger compressed tarball.)

#### master_repackager

Assuming you have the subdirectory notation, then you can do:

```
for master in "$@"
do
    tmp=$(pwd)/xyz.$$
    trap "rm -fr $tmp; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
    cat $master |
    (
    mkdir $tmp
    cd $tmp
    tar -xf -
    cd *        # There is only one directory in the newly created one!
    process_tarballs *
    cd ..
    tar -czf - *   # There is only one directory down here
    ) > new.$master
    rm -fr $tmp
    trap 0
done
```

If you're working in a malicious environment, use something other than `tmp.$$` for the directory name.  However, this sort of repackaging is usually not done in a malicious environment, and the chosen name based on process ID is sufficient to give everything a unique name.  The use of `tar -f -` for input and output allows you to switch directories but still handle relative pathnames on the command line.  There are likely other ways to handle that if you want.  I also used `cat` to feed the input to the sub-shell so that the top-to-bottom flow is clear; technically, I could improve things by using `) > new.$master < $master` at the end, but that hides some crucial information multiple lines later.

The trap commands make sure that (a) if the script is interrupted (signals HUP, INT, QUIT, PIPE or TERM), the temporary directory is removed and the exit status is 1 (not success) and (b) once the subdirectory is removed, the process can exit with a zero status.

You might need to check whether new.$master exists before overwriting it.  You might need to check that the extract operation actually extracted stuff.  You might need to check whether the sub-tarball processing actually worked.  If the master tarball extracts into multiple sub-directories, you need to convert the '`cd *`' line into some loop that iterates over the sub-directories it creates.

All these issues can be skipped if you know enough about the contents and nothing goes wrong.

#### process_tarballs

The second script is process_tarballs; it processes each of the tarballs on its command line in turn, extracting the file, making the substitutions, repackaging the result, etc.  One advantage of using two scripts is that you can test the tarball processing separately from the bigger task of dealing with a tarball containing multiple tarballs.  Again, life will be much easier if each of the sub-tarballs extracts into its own sub-directory; if any of them extracts into the current directory, make sure you create a new sub-directory for it.

```
for tarball in "$@"
do
    # Extract $tarball into sub-directory
    tar -xf $tarball
    # Locate appropriate sub-directory.
    (
    cd $subdirectory
    find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/name/alternative-name/g'
    )
    mv $tarball old.$tarball
    tar -cf $tarball $subdirectory
    rm -f old.$tarball
done
```

You should add traps to clean up here, too, so the script can be run in isolation from the master script above and still not leave any intermediate directories around.  In the context of the outer script, you might not need to be so careful to preserve the old tarball before the new is created (so `rm -f $tarbal` instead of the move and remove command), but treated in its own right, the script should be careful not to damage anything.

#### Summary

- What you're attempting is not trivial.
- Debuggability splits the job into two scripts that can be tested independently.
- Handling the corner cases is much easier when you know what is really in the files.

Comment: My case comes under the second scenario, where there are 4 to 5 tarballs inside the master tarball, not subdirectories. How do I handle that?

Comment: @GPX: You handle your situation carefully.  Think about what I showed; adapt it to your scenario.  Make sure you *do* have a unique directory to extract each of your tarballs into; it makes life a lot easier on the clean up.  You may want to derive the sub-directory name from the tarball name.

Answer (score 2):

You probably can `sed` the actual tar as tar itself does not do compression itself.

e.g.

`zcat archive.tar.gz|sed -e 's/foo/bar/g'|gzip > archive2.tar.gz`

However, beware that this will **also  replace foo with bar also in filenames, usernames and group names** and **ONLY works if *foo* and *bar* are of equal length**

Comment: That would definitely corrupt the tar file if the replacement string has a different length.