# Directly modifying uncompressed tar file

Tags: linux, unix, archive, tar, corruption

I have thousands of uncompressed tar files, which add up to almost 1 TB of data. Now i want to modify one specific string within some of the tar files.

Can I do this directly without extracting the tar file, e.g. with sed? Of course I do not want to get corrupted tar files.

---

Details:

The string I want to modify is 4 characters long. Can I replace it with another 4 character string? The [specification of a tar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_%28computing%29) seems to contain a checksum only for the header of each file contained in the tar file, and the length of each file, so replacing 4 characters within a file contained in the tar file with other 4 characters should be fine, right?

Can I even replace the 4 character string with a 6 character string? There seems to be some padding within tar files, so what is the probability of getting a corrupt tar file when adding 2 characters? How well does extraction still work for such a corrupted tar file?

I do not have nested tar files, so [this negative answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758565/modifying-files-nested-in-tar-archive) does not apply to my situation.

Comment: Extract the desired file from tar, modify it with sed, delete file from tar file and add modified file to tar file?

Comment: Yes, valid comment, Cyrus. But for 1TB of data, I think it's also valid to think about an optimized approach - hence the question.

Answer (score 2):

That is several questions:

- can you modify the content of files in a tar file (probably, since the file content has no checksum)
- what tool is useful (the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html) for `sed` is unclear, but others as in *[binary sed replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604964/binary-sed-replacement)* say "no", and suggest alternatives)
- can you replace a 4-character string with a 6-character string (probably not, since that changes the file-length, which requires adjusting the header and its checksum).

Comment: You are right, I formulated several questions. Your first bullet is by far the most relevant - a "probably no corruption" sounds kind of risky since I have a huge amount of tar files with important data.

Comment: Your second bullet was not intended as question: I know I can use sed for the replacements, I just mentioned it as an example of direct modification - as opposed to untar then modify then tar.

Comment: For what it's worth, a *quick check* seems to show that simple replacement by sed will work.  But it would be nice to have its behavior on binary files better-documented.

Answer (score 1):

I had to work with raw tar files some years ago, and it's nothing I could recommend.  There are too many "tar" formats to make sure your substitution was doing what you wanted it to do, and *only* what you wanted it to do.

In my case I had no choice and I had to use emacs to edit the tar file.  It was someone's backup.

If I had your problem, I'd take the time to write a small script/program to extract and `sed(1)` things to avoid a possible (maybe unlikely) corrupt archive.

Also, you probably have to run as root to ensure correct permissions and timestamps.